# Implement pagination using LINQ (on the server side)

Tags: linq, f#

I am using this code to get records from db:

```
use db = new dbml.MobileDataContext(connectionString)
query {
   for rows in db.Item do
   where (
            (orgid1   = "0" || rows.OrgId1 = orgid1) 
         )
   select rows
} |> (fun s ->
         if Seq.isEmpty s then
             [||]
         else
              s 
              |> Seq.skip offset |> Seq.take (int chunk) 
              |>  Seq.map sql.Record2Item |> Seq.toArray)
```

But if I look at query in SQL Profiler I see that LINQ return all records to client and get subset of records on the client.

But I need to have SQL query looks like:

```
... OFFSET " + offset + " ROW FETCH NEXT "  + chunk + " ROWS ONLY"
```

Is it possible to use pagination on the **server side** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution:

```
query {
   for rows in db.Item do
   select rows
   skip offset
   take chunk 
}
```